# bat file to open excel run macro close excel

Tags: excel, batch-file

Issue : I need to open an excel document, run the macro, save the document in a sepcific name (XXXX_YYYYMMDD), close excel document.

Solution 1:
I think i can use  a .bat file to open the excel, run the macro , save and rename the file.

Issue of solution 1:
a) I do not no how to pass the path of the file as a parameter.
b) I do know how write the process in script language for the .bat

Solution 2:
I think i can use  a .bat file to open the excel, and create a macro that once excel open it run and rename the excel and close it.

Issue of solution 1:
a) I do not no how to pass the path of the file as a parameter.

PS: Totally new with .bat coding

Other proposal are most welcome

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, you can pass the filename as a parameter by using

```
batfile.bat yourexcelfile.xls
```

and access it from the batch file using `%1`.

However, I don't know how to do the other macro things, but if you find out you can use this to put it together! :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is possible with BAt-Files, but I think a powersheel script could do it....
If this is not an option you might try to add the macro to the startup of the file - so it gets run when the file is opened...

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a hybrid bat/jscript file:

```
    rem ("open macro")/*
    @echo off
    call cscript //nologo //E:jscript excelfile.xsls
    goto :eof

    */
     var objExcel = new ActiveXObject ("Excel.Application"); 
     objExcel.Application.Run(""+WScript.Arguments.Item(0)+!mymacro"); 
    rem (){}
```

If the macro is embeded in a sheet you'll need to create a sheet object and access trough it.